# Why is my image convolution function so slow?

Tags: python, optimization, conv-neural-network, convolution, yolo

I wasn't sure if I should post this on the machine learning board or this one, but I chose this one since my problem has more to do with optimization. I am trying to build a YOLO model from scratch in python, but each convolution operation takes 10 seconds. Clearly I am doing something wrong, as YOLO is supposed to be super fast (able to produce results real-time). I don't need the network to run real-time, but it will be a nightmare trying to train it if it takes several hours to run on one image. How could I optimize the code below? Apparently there is a lot of room for improvement.

Here is my convolution function:

```py
def convolve(image, filter, stride, modifier):
    new_image = np.zeros ([image.shape[0], _round((image.shape[1]-filter.shape[1])/stride)+1, _round((image.shape[2]-filter.shape[2])/stride)+1], float)

    #convolve
    for channel in range (0, image.shape[0]):
        filterPositionX = 0
        filterPositionY = 0
        while filterPositionX < image.shape[1]-filter.shape[1]+1:
            while filterPositionY < image.shape[2]-filter.shape[2]+1:
                sum = 0
                for i in range(0,filter.shape[1]):
                    for j in range(0,filter.shape[2]):
                        if filterPositionX+i<image.shape[1] and filterPositionY+j<image.shape[2]:
                            sum += image[channel][filterPositionX+i][filterPositionY+j]*filter[channel][i][j]
                new_image[channel][int(filterPositionX/stride)][int(filterPositionY/stride)] = sum*modifier
                filterPositionY += stride
            filterPositionX += stride
            filterPositionY = 0

    #condense
    condensed_new_image = np.zeros ([new_image.shape[1], new_image.shape[2]], float)
    for i in range(0, new_image.shape[1]):
        for j in range(0, new_image.shape[2]):
            sum = 0
            for channel in range (0, new_image.shape[0]):
                sum += new_image[channel][i][j]
            condensed_new_image[i][j] = sum

    condensed_new_image = np.clip (condensed_new_image, 0, 255)

    return condensed_new_image
```

Running the function on a 448x448 grayscale image with a 7x7 filter and a stride of 2 takes about 10 seconds. My computer has an i7 processor.

Comment: "_as YOLO is supposed to be super fast_" ... based on what? This is heavily dependent upon the machine and type of processor it is running on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is it slow:** Because the time complexity of the function you coded is 
`O(n*n*n*k*k)`, where image size is `n*n` and filter size is `k*k`

**How to make it faster:** Avoid loops and use matrix operations (vectorize). Matrix operations are parallelized.

Comment: I will have to do some research on matrix operations. I had heard them mentioned before but I always assumed they still used loops under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Because it relays a lot in normal python code; i.e. your operations are performed element by element. You should vectorise them. Please take a look into this guide: https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/07/16/convnet-conv-layer/